# MVC3 Routing question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I just started to use the routes in MVC3 and I am totally confused. I hope I can get some advice on how I can do what I need from this site. Here is what I would like to do. First and most important I need all these links to go to the **Product** controller.

```
www.xx.com/product 12 code/         >> Action: Overview,  
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param

www.xx.com/product 12 code/Overview >> Action: Overview,  
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param

www.xx.com/product 12 code/Results  >> Action: Results,  
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param

www.xx.com/product 12 code/Product  >> Action: Product, 
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param
                                    >> Code=""   passed as a param

www.xx.com/product 12 code/Product/123 >> Action: Index, 
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param
                                    >> Code= 123 passed as a param
```

What I learned already is that I can get the "12" like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Route 1", // Route name
                "product {prodId} code/{action}/{id}",
                new 
                { 
                    controller = "Product", 
                    action = "Index", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional 
                }
            );
```

But how can I make it go to the different action events and pass the prodId and id as parameters? I think the route system is very powerful but complicated for a new user like me. How many routes do I need to set up to do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute("Route 1", // Route name
                "product {prodId}/{action}/{code}",
                new 
                { 
                    controller = "Product",   //default controller=Product
                    action = "Index",         //default action= Index
                    prodId = 12,              //default prodId=12
                    code=UrlParameter.Optional // code is optional
                }
            );






www.xx.com/product 12/         >> Action: Overview,  
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param

www.xx.com/product 12/Overview >> Action: Overview,  
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param

www.xx.com/product 12/Results  >> Action: Results,  
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param

www.xx.com/product 12/Product  >> Action: Product, 
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param
                                    >> Code=""   passed as a param

www.xx.com/product 12/Product/123 >> Action: Index, 
                                    >> ProdId=12 passed as a param
                                    >> Code= 123 passed as a param
```

Comment: Are you sure? I already have that working? That's the only part I understand. My problem is how I can set up the other routes. Maybe can someone confirm what you are saying? Thanks

Comment: i edited my answer, i just confirmed spaces in routes are valid, like the way you have done, but they can cause problems.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I'm sorry. I don't understand your route information. It looks like everything is hard coded to go to the Index action with a prodId of 12? Also I need it to go by default to the Overview action if the user doesn't specify an action.

Comment: Praveen I think you lost your edit. What I need is for ProdId=12 passed as a param to be passed when there's a 12 or ProdId=13 if there's a 13. I don't just want to code in 12 all the time. Also doesn't your code always set the action = Index ?? I want the action to be different sometime.

Comment: i think you need to read a bit carefully, before those claims

Comment: its not hard coded to call prod 13, you just need to change 12 to 13, you have  to understand prod=12 passed in route is just default value, it will be picked if you dont provide any prodId